# Report filter on 1-to-many joined tables

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that shows maintenance information for medical instruments. The selection criteria are based on several tables and fields. I needed to change the criteria, but results were not as expected. I managed to find the cause, but do not know what to do to get to the wanted situation.

So basically the problem is as follows:
I have 2 tables that are linked:
* **Equipment** (information related to a specific instrument eg EqmId)
* **ObjectFeature** (information related to a specific feature eg ObjfEqmId, ObjfId, ObjfYesno)

An equipment can have 0, 1 or many ObjectFeatures, and the tables are linked via
`Equipment.EqmId -> ObjectFeature.ObjfEqmId` with a left-outer join.

The problem I have is that i want to filter out al EqmId's where `(ObjfId="64" and ObjfYesno=1)`. I do not want to see these EqmId's in the final list.

In my current setup, I have only removed the ObjfId="64" lines, but since an EqmId can have multiple features, it still is present in the list...

In my original report **Equipment** is my main table, so I need a way to filter this table before I do further filtering and joining.

I find myself limited in the selection formula, and thought of using a SQL command on the database. But I can't get my head around how to do this.

How and where should I do the filtering?

Comment: your report is connected to table? or a procedure?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.   I made the report in CR, it just connects to this database, and I run the report automatically daily from within a scheduler.

Comment: can you explain the structure of this database?

Comment: The database I have comes from a FMS software called Ultimo. There are many tables, but the ones of interest right now are  * **Equipment** with index EqmId and  * **ObjectFeature** with index ObjfId and ObjfEqmId, which links to the index in Equipment

Comment: Can't you just add a conditoin to your query : `WHERE ObjfYesno <> 1` to filter out these values

Comment: No, because there are other ObjfId's (for any equipment) with a relevant ObjfYesno field that I want to see, regardless whether the value is 1 or 0.